# Correctly apply cumcount on this pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dateframe that looks like this

```
   ProductNumber   ProductVersion    DateStarted   
        AX1              R1          2018-01-01    
        AX1              R1          2018-01-02    
        AX1              R2          2018-01-03    
        AX1              R3          2018-01-04    
        AX1              R3          2018-01-05    
        BX1              R1          2018-01-01    
        BX1              R1          2018-01-02    
        AX1              R5          2018-01-03    
        AX1              R5          2018-01-04    
        AX1              R5          2018-01-05
```

I want to apply cumcount on the DateStarted column with respect to the ProductNumber such that I get the following dataframe.

```
   ProductNumber   ProductVersion    DateStarted   Count
        AX1              R1          2018-01-01    0
        AX1              R1          2018-01-02    1
        AX1              R2          2018-01-03    0 
        AX1              R3          2018-01-04    0
        AX1              R3          2018-01-05    1
        BX1              R1          2018-01-01    0
        BX1              R1          2018-01-02    1
        AX1              R5          2018-01-03    0
        AX1              R5          2018-01-04    1
        AX1              R5          2018-01-05    2
```

First i sort my values using

```
  df = d.sort_values(['ProductNumber','ProductVersion', 'DateStarted'], ascending = [True,True,True]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I then want to apply cumcount in some way, I tried doing it like this.

```
 df['count'] =(df.drop_duplicates(['ProductNumber','ProductVersion', 'DateStarted'])
  .groupby(['ProductNumber', 'ProductVersion'])['DateStarted']
  .cumcount())

 df['count'] = df['count'].ffill().astype(int)
```

But it doesn't work. How would I do this correctly?

EDIT: This is my output

```
   ProductNumber   ProductVersion    DateStarted   Count
        AX1              R1          2018-01-01    0
        AX1              R1          2018-01-02    0
        AX1              R2          2018-01-03    1 
        AX1              R3          2018-01-04    0
        AX1              R3          2018-01-05    1
        BX1              R1          2018-01-01    0
        BX1              R1          2018-01-02    0
        AX1              R5          2018-01-03    0
        AX1              R5          2018-01-04    1
        AX1              R5          2018-01-05    1
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work correctly"?

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct if you just shave off some stuff:

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['ProductNumber', 'ProductVersion']).cumcount()
df
```

Output:

```
  ProductNumber ProductVersion DateStarted  Count
0           AX1             R1  2018-01-01      0
1           AX1             R1  2018-01-02      1
2           AX1             R2  2018-01-03      0
3           AX1             R3  2018-01-04      0
4           AX1             R3  2018-01-05      1
5           BX1             R1  2018-01-01      0
6           BX1             R1  2018-01-02      1
7           AX1             R5  2018-01-03      0
8           AX1             R5  2018-01-04      1
9           AX1             R5  2018-01-05      2
```

Comment: It gives the output stated in the question for me. Do you mean it doesn't work for you on your full dataset, or also on what you posted in the question?